# How to create a responsive (regarding parent size) DIV with fixed aspect ratio and limited max-height?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, aspect-ratio

Keeping the aspect ratio of a `<div>` or similar element while being responsive to the parent's size seems to be a common problem. The solution that is widely regarded across the net as being the most elegant one is this:

[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div)
Using a wrapper element and defining the aspect ratio via the `width` and `padding-bottom` element, both of which are relative to the parent size.

```
div.wrapper {
   width: 30%;
   padding-bottom: 30%;
}
```

Now, my current problem is, that I need to introduce to introduce a `max-height` to these wrapper elements in order to make sure, that at least two rows of them fit the screen, independent of the viewport size. Adding `max-height` to the example above limits the element's height, but leaves the width unchanged.

However, an aspect ratio of 1:1 still needs to be maintained, even if the height is restricted via `max-height`. Also, I would like to have the group of wrapper elements (three or four columns, two rows) in the center of the viewport/parent.

Is there any pure html/css way to achieve this (without javascript)? I would not mind using `<img>` elements with a source of the desired ratio as I have to apply (background) images to these elements anyway but a universal, elegant solution as for the problem above would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your HTML Structure?

Comment: bootstrap will be useful

Comment: The one thing that comes to my mind is to create a wrapper div and give it a max-height and absolute positioning while giving your image a 100% width and relative positioning within that container. You'll have to figure out the max-width that gives you an appropriate height but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use below code :

```
div.wrapper{
     height:auto;
     width:30%;
}
```

Then Problem is Solved